# Converting Height values given like 5'6" and 4.58

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, nlp, python-re

We have recorded the height values from various students, but the students have written the values in different format like 5'11" and some have written 5.67.
We are trying to process this using split (".") we could able to split only values in decimals
and value of this kind **5'11"** is not splitting.

```
df1['Height']=df1['Height'].str.split(".")
 out:[5, 11]
     [5'6"]
```

Like above output, only one of value is getting converted not the other type of values .
please help me to convert both the values in one code so that we can convert them in meters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the value via `re.split`:

```
import re

values = ["1.2", "3'4"]
converted_values = []

for value in values:
    converted_values.append(re.split("[.']", value))

print(converted_values)
```

The output would be:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

But pay attention to resulting type - each value is a `list` of `str`-s.

If you need to get `float` value to be able to make math operations on it, you need a slightly different algorithm:

```
import re

values = ["1.2", "3'4"]
converted_values = []

for value in values:
    converted_values.append(float(value.replace("'", ".")))

print(converted_values)
```

This time the output will be:

```
[1.2, 3.4]
```